# Equivalencia My.computer a c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, filesystem

Tengo la siguiente linea en visual bAsic:

```
    Dim listadoArchivos = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(directorio, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, filtro)
```

la equivalencia en c# cual sería?

Comment: [`Directory.GetFiles()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2). De todas maneras, es algo sencillo de buscar en la documentacion....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directorio, filtro, System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```